# My web page is not working from a JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I was trying to figure out if there is a way of getting an API result (JSON) to an html table. The way I tried did not worked out.
I'm trying to get the JSON from the tfl API.

Here is the code snipped I'm currently working on:

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-border table-stiped" id="test_table"
<body>


<table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/1000012/to/1000172",function(data){
    var test_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      test_data += '<tr>';
      test_data += '<td>'+value.duration+'</td>';
   test_data += '<td>'+value.arrivalDateTime+'</td>';
   test_data += '<td>'+value.departureTime+'</td>';
      test_data += '</tr>';
      
    });
    $('#test_table').append(test_data);
  });
  });
</script>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please, elaborate what do you mean by "have not worked". Is there an error in console, blank screen, etc?

Comment: Hi Gamer. Welcome to StackOverflow! .I checked the api url in your code. The returned value is not consistant. Sometimes, it returns an array, sometimes a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before operate the JSON, try to understand theJSON structure (ajax response).
I have made some changes in snippet for reference (Working)

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-border table-stiped" id="test_table"
<body>


<table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Journey/JourneyResults/1000012/to/1000172",function(data){
    var test_data = '';
    $.each(data.journeys, function(key, value){
      test_data += '<tr>';
      test_data += '<td>'+value.duration+'</td>';
   test_data += '<td>'+value.arrivalDateTime+'</td>';
   test_data += '<td>'+value.startDateTime+'</td>';
      test_data += '</tr>';
      
    });
    $('#test_table').append(test_data);
  });
  });
</script>
</table>
```

Comment: Why the answer is down voted?, please comment for understand where I am making mistake

Comment: this worked fine thank you very much i did not down vote the anser but i can not oup vote it either as i have not got enough reputation